# Arduino Bluetooth Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, shields

A friend of mine bought two of these Bluetooth shields [here.](http://store.linksprite.com/bluetooth-4-0-ble-pro-shield-for-arduino-master-slave-and-ibeacon/) I have been trying to get the two Arduinos connected to each other through Bluetooth. I could not get it working myself but I found some code online [here](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=Bluetooth_Shield_for_Arduino) that I tried. The shields connect to each other (the lights on both turn red) but the I can't send data between them. Does anyone have any code that may works with these shields?